# KVM bridged interfaces not going up - inet, inet6 , bridge

Tags: networking, kvm, bridge, ipv6

I am setting up KVM host which will have multiple virtual machines visible from the outside with a similar `/etc/network/interfaces` config to this one

```
# The loopback network interface

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 2001:0000:1004:1019::
  netmask 64
  post-up /sbin/ip -family inet6 route add 2001:0000:1004:10ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev eth0
  post-up /sbin/ip -family inet6 route add default via 2001:0000:1004:10ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  pre-down /sbin/ip -family inet6 route del default via 2001:0000:1004:10ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  pre-down /sbin/ip -family inet6 route del 2001:0000:1004:10ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev eth0


auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address 41.100.60.25
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 41.100.60.0
  broadcast 41.100.60.255
  gateway 41.100.60.254
  bridge_ports eth0
  bridge_maxwait 12
  bridge_fd 9
  bridge_hello 2
  bridge_maxage 12
  bridge_stp off

  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
  dns-search ovh.net

  post-up ip link set br0 address xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

  post-up ip addr add 164.123.123.123/32 dev br0 broadcast 164.123.123.123
  post-down ip addr del 164.123.123.123/32 dev br0

  post-up ip route add default via 41.100.60.254 dev br0
  post-down ip route del default via 41.100.60.254 dev br0

  post-down brctl delbr br0
```

and both eth0 and br0 interfaces are being brought up in the end (they work) but I am seeing this when I look at the booting screen (it's not in the boot log for some reason):

```
Waiting for network configuration
Waiting upto 60 more seconds for network configuration"
Booting system without full network configuration
```

Additionally when I run

```
ifquery --state
```

or

```
cat /run/network/ifstate
```

I can see that eth0 and br0 are missing

```
lo=lo
```

**EDIT 1:**

By using the following command

```
ifup br0 --no-act
```

I got the following set of commands that are being run if you would use `ifup br0`

```
run-parts  /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
ip addr add 41.100.60.25/255.255.255.0 broadcast 41.100.60.255    dev br0 label br0
ip link set dev br0   up
 ip route add default via 41.100.60.254  dev br0 
ip link set br0 address xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
ip addr add 164.123.123.123/32 dev br0 broadcast 164.123.123.123
ip route add default via 41.100.60.254 dev br0
run-parts  /etc/network/if-up.d
```

Which tells me that this command gets duplicated

```
ip route add default via 41.100.60.254 dev br0
```

so after removing this from my config

```
post-up ip route add default via 41.100.60.254 dev br0
post-down ip route del default via 41.100.60.254 dev br0
```

I can see

```
run-parts  /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
ip addr add 41.100.60.25/255.255.255.0 broadcast 41.100.60.255    dev br0 label br0
ip link set dev br0   up
 ip route add default via 41.100.60.254  dev br0 
ip link set br0 address xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
ip addr add 164.123.123.123/32 dev br0 broadcast 164.123.123.123
run-parts  /etc/network/if-up.d
```

Which solves the problem of missing br0 AFTER REBOOT when I run

```
ifquery --state
# or
cat /run/network/ifstate
```

because I can see

```
lo=lo
br0=br0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to remove inet6 static configuration for now so I am good after the "EDIT 1".

I presume that having a configuration for inet and inet6 which has two different types for e.g. "static" and "manual" is causing some command duplication when running ifup and ifdown.